# Concerned I may have accidentally dropped malware (or something) onto my system

Tags: macos, permission, malware, anti-virus, virus

First time poster in this part of Stack Exchange - apologies I have posted in the wrong section.

In short I have an iMac running 10.8. Most of the time I quite happily get about my business but about every 3-4 years I do something stupid. Today was one of those days.

Basically I was looking at an alternative method of running Mame (currently use the OpenEmu route). Basically downloaded SDLMame, then was going to go the QMC2 front end route for a GUI. Downloaded both, but when downloading QMC2 (from what is a legitimate site) - installed the package and it installed a folder into my Applications folder with no permission to access it. In short, I didn't like that at all (as that is a fairly non-standard thing), deleted the folder (securely) without installing the application file, and then ran Intego Virus Scanner with week old definitions, and ClamXAV. Neither picked anything up when downloading the packages (I always check all downloads that way) and neither picked anything odd up on my system afterwards (after deleting). In short my iMac hasn't behaved erratically since but I just wish to be 100% so is there anything else further than I can do? I have also run Etre Check, and it didn't pull anything obviously abnormal except for the fact that I need to update my Flash as there has been a new recommended version released etc.

I expect I may be having an over-reaction and it is possibly standard for that emulator (had never used it before) but I take the better to be safe than sorry approach.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you did your due diligence and there is no evidence of a real malware problem - it sounds like their installer just screwed up the permissions.

Fire up Terminal, and do an `ls -l` of your `Applications` folder, looking for the QMC2 folder. I'd be willing to be it did something like installing as root (I bet the package asked for your password, right?) and missed correcting the permissions.

Once you've found it, you can do a `chown (your username) -R (QMC2 path)` to set everything to your user.

Comment: Thanks. Have been very busy at work this week so have only just had a chance to look at this. Have re-downloaded the package. Will re-install it and post the details. For what it's worth I remember the permissions said "fetching" or something like that if it helps.

Comment: Am thinking I may ask for this question to be closed - I think its clear I don't have Malware, it's more of an issue of how do you install QMC2. I'm not over familar with terminal but did this and it still pulled it; User8812-iMac:~ User8812$ ls /applications/
Intego    VLC.app
Kies.app   XLD
Launchpad.app   iMovie.app
MP3Gain Express.app  iPhoto.app
MPEG Streamclip.app  iTunes.app
Mail.app   qmc2

So it shows that it is there? - I edited the list down a touch. When running the actual app, it wouldn't run due to other issues - have screenshots but I didn't know how to post them?

Comment: @user8812 You'd probably just want to open a new question on this site then - since we're out of scope of the original question. Images are actually super easy, when you're in the question editing screen, there's a photo icon, you hit that, and it will prompt you for an upload.